# How to find index in a matrix using another list as a reference using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let A be a matrix:

```
A = array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.28867513, 0.28867513, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ],
   [0.        , 0.13363062, 0.13363062, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ]])

B = array([0.70710678, 0.66666667, 0.5       , 0.75      , 1.        ])
```

I need to find the indexes of B in A.

Expected Output:

```
Matrix containing position of elements.
```

I want to perform this using inbuilt numpy commands/ logic and not using list comprehension or for loops.

Update: Already tried using isin, unable to tackle multiple elements with same value in the same row.

Updated with a better example of the problem.

Comment: By find the values of B do you mean the first 0 and then the second 0 in A etc.? or the whole sequence 0,0,0,1,1 in this order in A?

Comment: B is the values whose index I intend to find from the matrix A. I want to iterate by row and find position of the elements in B which are in A.

Comment: So the length of B is the same as the number of columns in A? So you're looking for a row in A?

Comment: the shape of A is (507, 5434), the shape of B is (507,)

Comment: Are you looking for rows in A that are equal to B?

Comment: Yes, precisely row-wise index of the values which are equal to B.

Comment: Your original example made (some) sense.  This generalization does not.  We could reproduce the original; we can't copy your new arrays, much less recreate a vague "matrix" result.  Something to keep in mind is that exact matches with floats is difficult.  `np.isclose/np.allclose` are the best tools for comparing float arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.all` has a `axis` input so you can check if a row/column is all True. To get the index of the row you can use `np.where`

```
np.where(np.all(A==B, axis=1))
```

Comment: This was a relatively simple example; I am trying to perform this operation on a large matrix where there are multiple values being repeated. Already tried performing this it didn't come through.

Comment: Then you should ask the full question you want answered... Are the values in B unique? if yes, then this answer should work. Otherwise, edit the question with more info

Comment: sorry about that. I have updated the question.

Comment: Edited to answer the edited question

Comment: There's possibly a faster wat but for the dimensions you mentioned this should be very fast

Comment: This returns an error " axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0", tried modifying the dimensions too.. still stuck with the same error.

Comment: You have a problem of dimensions, for this to work you must have `len(B)==A.shape[1]`

Comment: I tried applying transposition to meet the above conditions as you mentioned, I am returned with an empty array

Comment: Then there are probably no matches... Try matching the first row from A to A itself, it should return the index 0..

Answer (score 0):

With your original example

```
In [436]: A = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
     ...:      [4, 5, 6, 7],
     ...:      [8, 9, 10, 11]]
     ...: 
     ...: B = [2, 5, 11]
```

A simple list comprehension produces:

```
In [437]: [a.index(b) for a,b in zip(A,B)]
Out[437]: [2, 1, 3]
```

`index` does only gives the first, and raises an error if there isn't a match.  We could write a cover function that addresses those issue, catching the error, and repeating itself.

If the inputs are arrays:

```
In [438]: AA = np.array(A); BB = np.array(B)
```

We can do a "row-wise" test:

```
In [439]: BB[:,None]==AA
Out[439]: 
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

and find all the True.  Your [2,1,3] is the 2nd array.

```
In [440]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[440]: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([2, 1, 3], dtype=int64))
```

again the match isn't so clean with there are variable numbers of matches per row.

If the values are floats, we could use `isclose` instead:

```
In [441]: np.isclose(BB[:,None],AA)
Out[441]: 
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

[Get all indexes of multiple values in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437658/get-all-indexes-of-multiple-values-in-numpy-array)

seeks multiple matches between two arrays.  Both arrays are 1d, but the responses illustrate the complications in working with multiple matches.