# Get all indexes of multiple values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

This is a generalization of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191029/getting-the-indices-of-several-elements-in-a-numpy-array-at-once).

I want the fastest way to find, for each element of `a`, all the indexes corresponding to this element in `b`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 10, 4, 4, 4])
```

Here the output would be `[[0], [1,2], [5,6,7]]`

Comment: Numpy does not support jagged arrays so I presume you're looking for a list as output. This is not very efficient. Instead you should consider accepting a 3x8 array of booleans.

Comment: `np.in1d` takes different approaches depending on the relative size of `a` and `b`.  For relatively small `a` is iterates on it, joining the results with `logical_and`.  If they are more equal it uses sorting.  The same sort of considerations may apply to your example.  While it is easy to get `a[:,None]==b`,, and even `np.nonzero` on that, separating the results into your lists will (most likely) require some sort of iteration on the dimension of `a`.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't worry about efficiency in iterating on `a`.  The only way you'll be able to use the resulting list of lists will a list iteration.